# Is my proof of first Kepler's Law correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, physics

I recently learned how to use differential equations in physics(just the basics), so I tried to prove First Kepler's  Law as a challenge. This is my proof, I would like to know if it is correct:

**Proof**

[image]

The first thing I did was decomposing the problem on $x$ and $y$. From the similidute of triangles we have:

$$ a_x:x=a:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Rightarrow a_x=a\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
$$ a_y:y=a:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\Rightarrow a_y=a\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$

Since $a_x=x''$ and $a_y=y''$ , we have:

$$x''=a\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$y''=a\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Since:

$$a=\frac{GM}{r^2}=\frac{GM}{x^2+y^2}$$

We'll have:
$$x''=\frac{GM}{x^2+y^2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$y''=\frac{GM}{x^2+y^2}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Here I got stumped for some days. Then I noticed that multiplying both sides:

$$x''y''=\frac{G^2M^2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^3}$$

I know it isn't formal, but I thought that the difficult part was the denominator. So I made this substitution:
$$x=c_1 \cos(c_2 t+c_3) $$
$$y=c_1 \sin(c_2 t+c_3) $$
This makes the denominator disappear and we have:

$$k_1\cos(c_2 t+c_3)\sin(c_2 t+c_3)=k_2\cos(c_2 t+c_3)\sin(c_2 t+c_3)$$

This proves that my solution was correct and that solution is the parametric equation of an ellipse(however this doesn't prove that it's unique, but I don't know how yet how to solve a differential equations system, so I had to use intuition and a bit of luck).

Thank you for your time

:)

Comment: Why will the denominator disappear?

Comment: Because $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$ (oh my bad the constant must be the same).

Comment: Yes, you denominator contains $a\sin^2(x)+b\cos^2(y)$, which is not $1$ (to be correct, it can be $1$ in special cases). And you are missing a negative sign from the acceleration, because the force is $F=-G \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$, or equivalently the potential is $V=-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}$.

Comment: The combinations you should consider are $\frac{d}{dt}(x'^2+y'^2)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}(x'y-xy')$. With the resulting 2 conserved quantities you can reduce the state or phase space from 4 dimensions to a 2-dimensional surface.

Comment: In order to prove Kepler's first law you should consider doing it in polar coordinates. It would first result in the conservation of angular momentum, which implies that the trajectory is in a single plane. Then you can show that the equation is that of a conic (can be parabola, hyperbola, ellipse, or circle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove Kepler's first law, take the total energy in polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)$, $$E_\text{total}=\frac12m\dot r+\frac{|\vec L|^2}{2mr^2}-G\frac{mM}{r},$$ where $L=|\vec L|$ is the angular momentum and solve this for $\dot r$:

$$\dot r=\left(\frac2m\left(E_\text{total}-\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}+G\frac{mM}{r}\right)\right)^{1/2}$$ and use $\dot\varphi=\frac{L}{mr^2}$ to get $$\frac{\mathrm d\varphi}{\mathrm dr}=\frac{\mathrm d\varphi}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dr}=\frac{L}{mr^2}\left(\frac2m\left(E_\text{total}-\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}+G\frac{mM}{r}\right)\right)^{-1/2}.$$
Now integrate this to get $\varphi(r)$ and solve this for $r$ to finally obtain $$r(\varphi)=\frac{a(1-b^2)}{1+b\cos\varphi}\qquad\text{for}\qquad a=-G\frac{mM}{2E_\text{total}}\quad\text{and}\quad b=\left(1+\frac{2E_\text{total}L^2}{G^2m^3M^2}\right)^{1/2}.$$

This is the equation of the conic section in polar coordinates. For $E_\text{total}<0$, this becomes the equation of an ellipse.